# Error 1001 LoaderExceptions

Tags: winforms, windows-installer

I've got an application that works in our corporate workplace on both Windows XP and Windows 7 PCs.

The application is built using Visual Studio 2008, and no new components have been added.

The solution includes a Visual Studio Installer that overrides the Committed event by asking if the person wants to launch the application:

```
public AcpInstaller() : base() {
  this.Committed += new InstallEventHandler(MyInstaller_Committed);
}

void MyInstaller_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e) {
  if (MessageBox.Show("Start ACP Suite now?", "Launch Application?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes) {
    try {
      Process p = new Process()
      {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Context.Parameters["assemblypath"])
      };
      p.Start();
    } catch (Exception err) {
      MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Launch Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
  }
}
```

We have recently added some new HP Mini Netbooks. These have 1.66GHz Atom processors, 2 GB of RAM, and Win7 Pro x32.

`Error 1001. Unable to get installer types in the <executable>
assembly. --> Unable to load one or more of the
requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.`

All of the Web shows people get this when going from VS2005 to VS2008 or VS2008 to VS2010.

That is not my case.

My installer and application currently works as it should on other PCs, but this netbook I am testing on is giving me problems.

How can I find out what this LoaderException is? I can't look in the Debugger, because this is during an Install (i.e. not during the debug process) and it is happening on a completely different machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help others.

The problem was in a 3rd Party Control (LabelView) that was not 64-bit compatible.

The application installs just fine as long as it is only ever built as an x86 project.

Comment: I find myself coming back here (twice already). For this particular LabelView control, uninstalling my program will "unregister" the LabelView DLL. To "reregister" the DLL, all I have to do is open LabelView again, then recompile the installer.